# Multithreaded client-server synch problem

Tags: c, multithreading

I am trying to build multithreaded client-server project where: each client inserts names and surnames in two queues, one for names and one for surnames. After the insertion, I create N working threads in order to find matches between the 2 queues. If a match is found (name == surname), the threads have to delete the matched nodes in both queues.

I am thinking two possible synchronisation scenarios:

1. one thread is working and N-1 are suspended in order to update the queues after the deletion of the matched nodes. But I think its inefficient because I dont have parallel thread execution.
2. 2 threads only update the queues and N-2 are only reading the queues simultaneously and I lock only the nodes that are being read or deleted.

The execution of the second scenario is below, but I am confused with the nested locks.

The code below is for the server. The clients only insert names in the queues.

The **updateOne** thread is waiting until condition variable **update** become 1. If it is one, deletes the matched nodes and turns condition variable **update** to 0 and releases func thread.

I want two things for the desired sync scenario:

1. func threads run continuously  until the find 3 matches. If a node is being deleted, they have to read the rest of the queue, not to be suspended

**Question 1** : **How can I have the rest of the func threads working and not suspended?
**
2) updateOne threads can acquire the reader lock in order to traverse the queue and delete the matched nodes, while func threads read the rest of nodes

**Question 2** : **How can I use readerLock in order to lock at a node level not at the queue level?**

**Question 3** : **Does pop_from_index work properly?**

```
#include "list.h"


typedef struct info {
    node *info_buy;
    node *info_sell;
}info;
int update = 0;
int matches = 0;
pthread_mutex_t reader_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t update_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t condition = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void *updateOne (void *args){

    info *arg = (info *)args;
    node *temp_buy = arg->info_buy;
    node *temp_sell = arg->info_sell;
    printf("waiting\n");
    while (1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&update_lock);

        while (update != 1){
            pthread_cond_wait(&condition, &update_lock);
        }

        printf("woke up\n");

        node *tb = temp_buy;
        node *ts = temp_sell;


        int index_to_delete = -1;
        while (tb != NULL){
            if (tb->valid == 0){
                index_to_delete = tb->n;
                printf("Index buy %d\n", tb->n);
                pop_from_index(&temp_buy, index_to_delete);
            }
            tb = tb->next;
        }
        printList(temp_buy);

        while (ts != NULL){
            if (ts->valid == 0){
                index_to_delete = ts->n;
                printf("Index sell %d\n", ts->n);

                pop_from_index(&temp_sell, index_to_delete);

            }
            ts = ts->next;
        }
        printList(temp_sell);

        update = 0;
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&condition);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&update_lock);
    }

    return NULL;
}

void *func(void *args)
{
    // Store the value argument passed to this thread

    /*info *n = (info*) args;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&reader_lock);
    int index = -1;
    node *t1 = n->info_buy;
    while (t1 != NULL){
        node *t2 = n->info_sell;
        while (t2 != NULL){

            if (strcmp(t1->command, t2->command) == 0){

                pthread_mutex_lock(&update_lock);

                update = 1;

                pthread_cond_broadcast(&condition);

                t1->valid = 1;

                t2->valid = 1;

                pthread_mutex_unlock(&update_lock);

                break;
            }
            t2 = t2->next;
        }
        t1 = t1->next;

    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&reader_lock);
*/



    info *queues = (info *) args;
    node *buy = queues->info_buy;
    node *sell = queues->info_sell;


    while (1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&reader_lock);

        node *tb = buy;

        while (tb != NULL){

            node *ts = sell;
            while (ts != NULL){
                pthread_mutex_lock(&update_lock);

                sleep(1);
                while (update == 1){
                    pthread_cond_wait(&condition, &update_lock);
                }

                if (strcmp(ts->command, tb->command) == 0){
                    matches++;
                    if (matches >= 3){
                        break;
                    }
                    printf("*** Matched! ***\n");
                    printf("Matched pair --> (%s, %s)\n", ts->command, tb->command);
                    ts->valid = 0;
                    tb->valid = 0;

                    update = 1;
                    pthread_cond_broadcast(&condition);
                }
                ts = ts->next;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&update_lock);

            }
            tb = tb->next;
        }
        if (matches >= 3){
            break;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&reader_lock);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *destroy_list(void *args){

    pthread_mutex_lock(&update_lock);

    info *queues = (info *)args;

    destroyList(&(queues->info_buy));

    destroyList(&(queues->info_sell));

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&update_lock);

    return NULL;
}

int main(){

    pthread_t workingThreads[5];
    pthread_t updateThreads[2];
    pthread_t destroy[2];
    pthread_cond_init(&condition, NULL);

    if (pthread_mutex_init(&reader_lock, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("\n mutex init has failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (pthread_mutex_init(&update_lock, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("\n mutex init has failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    node *sell = NULL;
    node *buy = NULL;

    push(&sell, "Maria");
    push(&sell, "Sam");
    push(&sell, "Tom");
    push(&sell, "Takis");

    push(&buy, "Mary");
    push(&buy, "Edgar");
    push(&buy, "Marx");
    push(&buy, "Takis");
//
//

    info *ptr = malloc(sizeof(info));

    ptr->info_buy = sell;
    ptr->info_sell = buy;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        pthread_create(&(updateThreads[i]), NULL, updateOne, ptr);
    }

    pthread_create(&(workingThreads[0]), NULL, func, ptr);
    pthread_create(&(workingThreads[1]), NULL, func, ptr);
    pthread_create(&(workingThreads[2]), NULL, func, ptr);
    pthread_create(&(workingThreads[3]), NULL, func, ptr);
    pthread_create(&(workingThreads[4]), NULL, func, ptr);

//    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
//        pthread_create(&(destroy[i]), NULL, destroy_list, ptr);
//    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        pthread_join(updateThreads[i], NULL);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        pthread_join(workingThreads[i], NULL);
    }



    pthread_mutex_destroy(&reader_lock);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&update_lock);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&condition);

    destroyList(&sell);
    destroyList(&buy);

    return 0;
}
```

```
void pop_from_index (node **head, int index){
    


    if ((*head) == NULL){
        return;
    }

    node * temp = (*head);

    if (index == 0){
        *head = temp->next;

        free(temp);

        return;
    }

    for (int i=0; temp!=NULL && i< index - 1; i++){
        temp = temp->next;

    }
    
    // If position is more than number of nodes
    if (temp == NULL || temp->next == NULL)
        return;

    // Node temp->next is the node to be deleted
    // Store pointer to the next of node to be deleted
    struct node *next = temp->next->next;

    free(temp->next);  // Free memory

    temp->next = next;  // Unlink the deleted node from list
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a mutex. It's very complicated but in simple words it's a lock/unlock mechanism for the case that more than one thread tries to access the same data, or in other words: synchronisation between threads. I think [this article](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/c-mutex-examples/) will give you a fairly good idea of the topic.